# I'm getting an exception when parsing JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, try-catch, explain

I'm making a program for saving passwords (only for me)

```
with open(file, mode='w', encoding='Latin-1') as FA:
    try:
        FAJ = json.load(FA)
    except Exception:
        tafa = {tarr[0]: {'login': tarr[1], 'password': tarr[2]}}
        json.dump(tafa, FA)
    else:
        FAJ[tarr[0]] = {'login': tarr[1], 'password': tarr[2]}
        json.dump(FAJ, FA)
    finally:
        FAJ.close()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        os.system('pause')
        menu()
```

I'm trying to catch an error and check if the file is empty.
But even if file is not empty it anyways throws exception. Does anyone know what could be a problem?

Comment: An empty file contains nothing. That's not valid json and will cause a JSONDecodeError.

Comment: goo.gl/2Kng3g (screenshot)

Comment: The error is in the `json` module. It's not a builtin. `json.JSONDecodeError`

Comment: Okay, How I can make all right ?

Answer (score 2):

You open your file for *writing*: `open(file, mode='w', ...)`. You cannot read from it, and it also truncates the file. Remove the `mode` parameter. The default `open` behavior is to open the file for reading.

Comment: It's mean what I need open two files ? which I'll be use as json.dump and json.load ?